# Can the PS4 play downloaded movies without an internet connection?

Tags: ps4

I have a lot of movies I downloaded from the store and which will not play without internet. Can movies downloaded from the Playstation Store be played without the internet and if so how?

Answer (score 3):

No. It needs a connection to verify and retrieve the licenses to play them. :(